# How to post data to controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am unable to get data from Ajax at CI controller
this is my javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {id:list_id},
    url: "<?php echo site_url('xxx')?>",
    success: function(data)
    {
      alert(data);           
    }
});
```

at my controller, I try to get **id** with

```
$list_id = $_POST['id'];
```

or

```
$list_id = $this->input->post('id');
```

but still didn't get id data

Comment: Show your ajax code

Comment: echo site_url('xxx'), is this url  point to your controllers action ??

Comment: change this line data: {id:list_id}, to data: {'id':list_id},

Comment: are you sending any data to `list_id` from ajax?

Comment: check your console is there any error?

Comment: i edit my question, yes xxx is my url controller

Comment: try to put ; after echoing the url

Comment: Add this argument and try `dataType: "jsonp",`

Comment: Did you try any of the answers below. If they helped don't for get to accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var list_id=2;
  console.log(list_id)
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {"id":list_id},
                url: "<?php echo site_url('xxx') ?>",
                success: function(data)
                {
                  alert(data);

                }
            });
```

if your using chrome then

1. `inspect element` and click on `network` in that click your `request` after that click on `header` and check you post data whether is send from ajax or not.
2. or you can use  `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die;` to check inside your controller.

Note : check this image

[image]

At the bottom of the image showed your post data.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
data: {id:list_id},
```

to

```
data: {'id':list_id},
```

and in your controller use $id =  $_POST['id']; `// Added inverted comma here in key`

Comment: both {id:list_id} and {'id':list_id} are same

Comment: In json keys are wrapped in ' ,when there is a space or '-' in the key, here id doesnt need to be 'id', both are same

Comment: Oh , Thank you for the information @AnanthakrishnanBaji

Answer (score 0):

if you console the url, does it give a complete and correct path to your controller method? Please check that; and ensure list_id is not an undefined variable

```
console.log(your post url here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line 
data: "id="+list_id,

This will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {id:list_id},
                url: "<?php echo site_url('xxx')?>",
                success: function(data)
                {
                  myFunction(data);

                }
            });  
myFunction:function(data){
alert(data);
}
```

Comment: u can access the data in a function and use it like above

Comment: Rather than just posting code explain what you changed and what needs to be changed etc.

Comment: I have already explained in one line above, as you want to access the data in controller for that you can just pass the data in a function call inside ur ajax request and from there you can access it. FYI sometimes just code is enough to understand the doubt rather than getting a theory over it

Answer (score 0):

If your Ajax Script is at the end of the page then you should try this: ( it will work with external `.js` the file just need to call it before the external `.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //var list_id = //add your code for where you get the id

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:list_id},
        url: base_url+"your_controller/your_function",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(jqXHR);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown); 
            // This will gives you alert if ajax fail
        }
    });
</script>
```

and to get the id in the controller

```
public function your_function(){

    $list_id = $this->input->post('id');
    echo $list_id;

}
```